# Journal Name not appearing in Bibliography

Tags: biblatex

Using LuaLaTeX and biber with Texmaker on a Mac

When citing an article like the following, everything in the bibliography is printed correctly only the **Journal Name** is not printed at all.  It should be displayed after "In: " I have no idea why this happens, for other identifiers like `@book` or `@inproceedings` its working fine.

> [1] Woodland, S., Crocombe, A. D., Chew, J. W. und Mills, S. J.: A New Method for Measuring Thermal Contact Conductance—Experimental Technique and Results. In: 133.7 (07/2011), S. 071601. doi: 10.1115/1.4001770 (s. S. 2).

```
@article{woodland_new_2011,
    title = {A {New} {Method} for {Measuring} {Thermal} {Contact} {Conductance}—{Experimental} {Technique} and {Results}},
    volume = {133},
    issn = {0742-4795, 1528-8919},
    url = {https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/gasturbinespower/article/doi/10.1115/1.4001770/466203/A-New-Method-for-Measuring-Thermal-Contact},
    doi = {10.1115/1.4001770},
    abstract = {Thermal contact conductance (TCC) is used to characterize heat transfer across interfaces in contact. },
    language = {en},
    number = {7},
    urldate = {2020-04-29},
    journal = {Journal of Engineering for Gas Turbines and Power},
    author = {Woodland, Simon and Crocombe, Andrew D. and Chew, John W. and Mills, Stephen J.},
    month = jul,
    year = {2011},
    pages = {071601},
    file = {Submitted Version:/Users/hanneshenglein/Zotero/storage/7MGEHYCI/Woodland et al. - 2011 - A New Method for Measuring Thermal Contact Conduct.pdf:application/pdf}
}
```

Redefined bibmacro

```
 %% Only used by article driver: Journal Volume.Number (date)
 \newbibmacro*{journal+volume+date}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
   {}
   {%
    \newunit
    \printfield{series}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
   }
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit
 }
```

Driver for articles:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+volume+date}%
  \usebibmacro{pages}%
  %\usebibmacro{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  %\iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
   %{\printfield{issn}}
   %{}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
   {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}}
   {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Mhhh, I'm afraid you will have to share some more details abut your document with us. Do you get any errors or warnings in the `.log` or `.blg` files? If I turn your code into a fully compilable example document I do get to see the journal: https://gist.github.com/moewew/932f4309f89e37b1121da4734572c3ee. Can you please turn the code snippets shown so far into a compilable document not unlike the one I posted that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Thank You for your answer!
I did a complete new setup of my latex document, taking a fresh copy of the template I have to use, and now it works! Everything is printed correctly. But it still seems to be a very strange error...

Comment: It would be a strange error, yes. But without any more info to investigate it, I'm afraid there is nothing we can do.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem cannot be reproduced from the code shown in the question and apparently resolved itself. It seems no longer possible to investigate the problem and so the question is unlikely to be of any use for future visitors and unlikely to be answered.